# Wordpress only displaying post with post ID 1

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have a WP query but it will only display the post with the ID of 1.

This is my code

```
<div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1" style="padding-top: 70px; padding-bottom:50px;">
    <?php $my_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => '5', 'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC', 'category_name' => 'health', 'orderby' => 'date'  ) );
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
  $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;
  $cats = get_the_category();
$cat_name = $cats[0]->name; ?>
    <h1 class="categoryName"><?php echo $cat_name ?></h1>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 productBox">
        <div class="productBoxBG" style="background: url(<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'hero_image' ); echo $image[0];?>);">

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 captionBox">
            <p style="padding-top: 10px"><?php the_field('snacks'); ?></p>
            <p class="productName"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
            <p class="productExcerpt"><?php echo get_excerpt(140); ?></p>
        </div>



</div>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

</div>
```

Any ideas as to why it would only show the one post with that specific ID? It's driving me insane.

Answer (score 0):

you can read the wordpress codex here : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

for the right way to create query in wp for example like this to show one post with specific ID

```
$id = 3;    
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_in' => $id ) );
```